# SAP HANA Sqoop Import

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hana, data-ingestion

I am trying to sqoop import from a HANA view. I have tried many ways and it still persists. Anyone had a similar experience and also please help me figure out if I m missing something:

Sqoop Job :

> sqoop import --driver com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver --connect
>   'jdbc:sap://hostname:30015?currentschema="_SYS_BIC"' --username
>   HDP_READ --password-file /path/vangaphx/clrhanapwd --query 'SELECT *
>   from ZFI_LOS_SUMMARY_NET_GROSS WHERE $CONDITIONS' --delete-target-dir
>   --target-dir /user/vangaphx/well2/SAPdatazone --num-mappers 1

Error:
[image]

Comment: Here is the image for the error :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTESx.jpg

Comment: The error message in your screenshot says “authentication failed” which means either the user name, the password or both are incorrect to logon to the HANA system. So, check that you are actually able to logon with this logon credentials. Also, setting the current schema to _SYS_BIC will not really help as it only shortens the naming path to design time views that have been activated. Given the name of your table/view in the example, this is not the case for the query you posted.

Comment: @LarsBr.I even tried using the fully qualified name for the HANA view provided to me. I thoroughly checked with the client. The user name and  password seems to absolutely correct.